# ItemChangeListener with more than 1 view

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, itemlistener

Hello I have ItemChangeListener... but I want this to be responsible for more than one view. ( If this is not the right way to do this please tell me how else ) So that when I choose an item in a JComboBox I get to work with that object I selected

```
public class ItemChangeListener implements ItemListener {

Persoon selectedPerson;
PersoonView view;


    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
        if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            Object item = event.getItem();
            // do something with object
            if(item instanceof Persoon) {
                this.selectedPerson = (Persoon) item;
                view.setOverzicht(this.selectedPerson);
            } else {
                this.selectedPerson = null;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

But as u can see right now.. It only works with one specific view the PersoonView view class. How should I modify this to work with more than one view?

edit: 
In my view I do this ( right now I have 2 view )

```
personenList = new JComboBox();
    for (Persoon p : app.getPersonen()) {
        personenList.addItem(p.getNaam());
    }

    personenList.addItemListener(new ItemChangeListener());
```

Everytime I select another item I want to get the selectedPerson to work with in that view for example I want to do this in my ActionListener that is in my view.

```
selectedPerson.voegtoeRek(new Rekening(Integer.parseInt(nieuwnr.getText()), selectedPerson));
```

So practically I need to find some way to get that variabel out of ItemChangeListener.

Comment: there I can't see any issue

Comment: I have 2 view that call this personenList.addItemListener(new ItemChangeListener()); Both this views have a method to update a JTextArea with info about the item selected. How can the itemchangelistener let the correct methode know what view to choose?

Comment: do you [mean (only sceleton)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19511300/714968), or there could be 2D array as source for JComboBox, one, two three JComboBoxes (somehting like as `Vector<Vector>`, Map or AbstractTableModel too), then selection in JComboBox can returns any value from linked, related row

Comment: btw this question is about 1. closing votes (unclear what ...) 2. edit with an SSCCE, and better description

Comment: I modified my question I hope its clear now

Answer (score 0):

create an interface with `setOverzicht(Persoon person)` method which can be inserted in listener constructor. The only thing you need then is to implement the interface if you want to use this listener.

Comment: I mean more like.. Do I have to let my itemChangeListener return the person item? ( therefore make a getter ) so that I can work with it in my view or what? and if I have to make a getter how should this look like?