# Change JPanel based on JList click

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I am having trouble updating one of my `JPanel` based on a `JList` click found in another panel. I have tried using the code I found here:

[repaint JPanel with every click at JList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510789/repaint-jpanel-with-every-click-at-jlist)

but I still have issues. I have pasted my code below:

```
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class SelectionFrame extends JFrame {
    private BufferedImage backgroundImage;  
    private JList<Object> superClassList;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private CharacterListPanel clp;
    private CharacterDetailsPanel cdp;
    private CardLayout card = new CardLayout();

    protected SelectionFrame() {
        // Create the background image
        try {
            backgroundImage = ImageIO.read(new File(GUIConfig.DEFAULT_GAME_BACKGROUND));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Set the title to the default
        setTitle(GUIConfig.DEFAULT_GAME_TITLE);

        // Set the frame background
        contentPane = new JPanel(){ 

            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(Gui.class.getResource("/others/background_1.png"));  
                g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), this);  
               }  
        };

        contentPane.setBackground(new Color(238, 238, 238));
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        // Add Character List Panel to JFrame
        clp = new CharacterListPanel();
        cdp = new CharacterDetailsPanel();

        add(clp, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        add(cdp, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

        // Grab its list and store it in super class list
        superClassList = clp.getCharacterList();

        // List for change in list
        superClassList.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                    String selectedVal = superClassList.getSelectedValue().toString();
                    System.out.println(selectedVal);
                    cdp.setName(selectedVal);
                    repaint();
                }
            }
        });

        // Set the size of the frame to the default, center frame, hide top level and do not allow resizing
        setSize(GUIConfig.DEFAULT_SELECTION_MENU_WIDTH, GUIConfig.DEFAULT_SELECTION_MENU_HEIGHT);
        setLocation(GUIConfig.HALF_DIMENSION_WIDTH - (int) this.getSize().getWidth()/2, GUIConfig.HALF_DIMENSION_HEIGHT - (int) this.getSize().getHeight()/2);
        setUndecorated(true);
        setResizable(false);
        pack();

        // Show frame
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    // This sub class is used to display the list of playable characters. it will include the character name and character icon
    class CharacterListPanel extends JPanel {
        private JList<Object> characterList;

        protected CharacterListPanel() {
            // Create list to hold name and icon for characters
            characterList = new JList<Object>();

            // Set list details
            characterList.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            characterList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

            // Map of characters
            Map<Object, ImageIcon> characters = new HashMap<Object, ImageIcon>();

            // Loop through default character names and retrieve character icon file paths
            for(int i = 0; i < GUIConfig.DEFAULT_CHARACTER_NAMES.size(); i+=1) {
                ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(GUIConfig.DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SYMBOLS.get(GUIConfig.DEFAULT_CHARACTER_NAMES.get(i)));
                characters.put(GUIConfig.DEFAULT_CHARACTER_NAMES.get(i), img);
            }

            // Add items to the list
            characterList.setListData(GUIConfig.DEFAULT_CHARACTER_NAMES.toArray());
            characterList.setCellRenderer(new IconListRenderer(characters));

            // Add list to JPanel
            add(characterList);

            // Remove grey background of JPanel
            setOpaque(false);
        }

        protected JList<Object> getCharacterList() {
            return characterList;
        }
    }

    // This sub class is used to display the character details card based on what the user has selected in the list
    class CharacterDetailsPanel extends JPanel {
        private String name = null;

        protected CharacterDetailsPanel() {
            System.out.println(getName());
            if(getName() == null || getName().isEmpty()){
                try {
                    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(GUIConfig.DEFAULT_CHARACTER_DETAILS.get("Default")));
                    JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));
                    add(picLabel);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(GUIConfig.DEFAULT_CHARACTER_DETAILS.get(getName())));
                    JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));
                    add(picLabel);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


            // Remove grey background of JPanel
            setOpaque(false);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SelectionFrame sf = new SelectionFrame();
    }
}
```

In my current iteration above the code is not like that in the link. The reason for this is that I tried code there; I literally copied and pasted and worked my way through it, and nothing happened. I think this is because in his case it's a list added directly to the frame and a panel. In my case its a list in a panel and another panel added to the `JFrame`. So like I said the code above abandon the sample found in the link. Instead what I tried to do was create the panels add them to the frame, and edit the panel I wanted changed every time a click happened by changing its name value; the name value is used to get the proper file.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to understand how to create a minimal code example. Just copy/pasting your current code doesn't make for a good question.

Comment: @Duncan *"Just copy/pasting your current code doesn't make for a good question."* Especially given the supplied code will not compile cleanly due to missing classes, and would not run the same for missing images.  OP: One way to get image(s) for an example is to **hot link** to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556).

Comment: BTW - for changing the panels, use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).

Answer (score 0):

Calling `repaint()` has no effect in your situation because the name set in `CharacterDetailsPanel` is evaluated during construction of `CharacterDetailsPanel` so your `else` branch can never be executed.
Instead you could store the `JLabel` where you set the image as a member and update the image when calling `setName`.